# Visibility of Universal app on iTunes for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app

I have just release a Universal app for iOS, I am able to see the Universal app in iPad apps store but I cannot see the same app in iPhone app store.

My question - Is there a Time difference for visibility of app on iPad and iPhone app store ?
How long does it take to get the app visible in iPhone app store ?

Comment: If you're on an iPad, you probably won't see a universal app in the iPhone section. Try from an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has to update the caches for iTunes, it can take between minutes and a day for it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I can now see my app on both the device iPad and iPhone. It was just matter of time. It takes time to get our app visible on both the device app store, depending on the traffic.